# Error when upgrade WP7 project to WP8 using VS2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, upgrade

When I try to upgrade my current WP7 project to a WP8 version using VS2012 built-in feature "Upgrade to Windows Phone 8.0"

I received an error message:

> Upgrade to the project could not be completed.
>   Object reference not set to an instance object.

This error has little useful information to work with, how to solve it?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, got tired of looking for answers, and then created a new WP8 project and copied my files over.  Worked OK, although not logical to do at all.

Comment: Thanks for your method, maybe I will try it at last, but there are so many files in my project :( ....

Answer (score 1):

If you want run app in WP 8 devices, perhaps you'll have a problem with the screen resolution on devices HTC. The best way is create new WP 8 project and share (add as link) most of the .cs and .xaml files of your WP7 project. I did it guided by the article http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application
Good luck!

Comment: In fact, it is not as difficult as it seems to move the files to a new project, but some controls (LongListSelector) now in the official SDK, and even small changes. By the way you use a maps in the project?

Comment: I have contacted a tech supporter of MS. After 2 hours working ,he told me that I should create a new project and copy the code from the old project - -

Comment: probably it's the official way to update / porting applications to a new version

Comment: avoid the auto method, to apply by hand is such painful :(

Comment: Unfortunately fully automatic method is improbable, because there have been some changes, such as LongListSelector now in the official SDK (slightly changed as its structure), and others, respectively you need to change the logic in some code. Maybe it's small changes, but for the automatic method is not possible.